# Edge detection - bad detection

Tags: c++, matlab, image-processing, edge-detection

Hello you all and thank you
I am a student and I am writing a c++ code to my final project.
My code problem is with *Edge Detection* algorithm (Image processing),
while i am running   *Edge Detection* algorithm in MATLAB I gets a good Edge detection, but if I am running the algorithm code written in c++, the created picture is with bad detection.

I tried to detect the edge with Matlb by using threshold of 0.03 and the detection was great( the changes in my project is very low (little changes on white surface).

Thank you so much
Idan.

maybe someone can help me, this is my code:

```
void ApplySobelFilter(unsigned char src[][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS], float Threshold)
{
    unsigned char dst[NUMBER_OF_ROWS][NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS];
    unsigned char * ptrToImage;
    ptrToImage = dst[0];
    // Kernels for sobel operator
    int Kernel_X[3][3] = { { -1, 0, 1 },{ -2, 0, 2 },{ -1, 0, 1 } };
    int Kernel_Y[3][3] = { { 1, 2, 1 },{ 0, 0, 0 },{ -1, -2, -1 } };
    // clears destination image
    for (int pixel = 0; pixel < NUMBER_OF_ROWS*NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; pixel++)
        *ptrToImage++ = 0;

    for (int row = 1; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS - 1; row++)
        for (int column = 1; column < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS - 1; column++)
        {

            double Gtot = 0;
            int Gx = 0;
            int Gy = 0;

            for (int x = -1; x <= 1; x++)
                for (int y = -1; y <= 1; y++)
                {
                    Gx += src[row + y][column + x] * Kernel_X[y + 1][x + 1];
                    Gy += src[row + y][column + x] * Kernel_Y[y + 1][x + 1];

                }

            Gtot = sqrt(double(Gx ^ 2 + Gy ^ 2));

            if (Gtot >= Threshold)
                dst[row][column] = 255;

            else
                dst[row][column] = 0;

        }

    for (int row = 0; row < NUMBER_OF_ROWS; row++)
    {
        for (int col = 0; col < NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS; col++)
        {
            src[row][col] = dst[row][col];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Idan, welcome to stuck overflow! Are you familiar with OpenCV library? it's a c++ library with image processing abilities. It also contains the Sobel function. For more information: http://opencv.org/

Comment: Can you post some images (expected and result)? Or, at least links to them?

Comment: One other thing, is your image a grayScale image?

Answer (score 2):

```
Gtot = sqrt(double(Gx ^ 2 + Gy ^ 2));
```

That's probably not doing what you expect. The operator `^` computes bit-wise xor, not power. In your case it simply flips the second bit of Gx and Gy. Squaring the variables can be done e.g. like this:

```
Gtot = sqrt(double(Gx * Gx + Gy * Gy));
```

Comment: thank you, I changed the code, but it still with very bad edge detection

Comment: If you are using 0.03 as threshold then that might be wrong. In Matlab, images often have a floating-point range in [0,1], wheras you seem to be dealing with an integer range in [0,255]. I think the corresponding threshold for your case would be roughly 8.

Comment: thank you, but it still not work... maybe do you know other very good edge detection code?